# How do I create a scheduling system based on the week of the year

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with columns date, day and week of the year.

I need to use week of the year to create a new column with values from 1 to 5.

Lets say i'm on week 35 all the columns with week 35 should have one, the weeks with 36 should have 2 and so on. 
Once it reaches week 40 and number 5 the numbers in the new column need to start from 1 at week 41 and continue in this kind of pattern for however long the data range is

```
def date_table(start='2019-08-26', end='2019-10-27'):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
    df["Day"] = df.Date.dt.weekday_name
    df["Week"] = df.Date.dt.weekofyear
    return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the index using modulo and the weeknumber:

```
import pandas as pd

start='2019-08-26'
end='2019-10-27'
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
df["Day"] = df.Date.dt.weekday_name
df["Week"] = df.Date.dt.weekofyear
df["idx"] = df["Week"] % 5 +1        # n % 5 = 0..4 plus 1 == 1..5 

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0  2019-08-26     Monday    35    1
[...]
6  2019-09-01     Sunday    35    1
7  2019-09-02     Monday    36    2
[...]
13 2019-09-08     Sunday    36    2
14 2019-09-09     Monday    37    3
[...]
20 2019-09-15     Sunday    37    3
21 2019-09-16     Monday    38    4
[...]
27 2019-09-22     Sunday    38    4
28 2019-09-23     Monday    39    5
[...]
34 2019-09-29     Sunday    39    5
35 2019-09-30     Monday    40    1
[...]

[63 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

If you want it to start on a *not by 5 divisible weeknumber* - you can do that too by substracting the modulo 5 value of the first week for all weeknumbers:

```
# startweeknumber:
startweekmod = df["Week"][0] % 5

# offset by inital weeks mod
df["idx"] = (df["Week"] - startweekmod) % 5 + 1
```